# php mongodb: how to push elements to array in a document?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

My document where data is to be inserted is:
Data has to be appended to array with `key` as `Solutions`

Suppose `$data` has some numerical value

```
array(8) {
["_id"]=>
object(MongoId)#9 (1) {
["$id"]=>
string(24) "56d32613097ed36c10000049"
}
["Username"]=>
string(4) "xxx"
["Solutions"]=>
array(0) {
}
}
```

Suppose `$j= "The entire above array"`
How to `push` the value of `$data` in the array having `key` as `"Solutions"`?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788220/mongodb-push-into-an-array-based-on-a-variables-contents